# Java Script - Loading image into a property

Tags: javascript, web, properties

I am using the [Snowstorm.js](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/snowstorm/) javascript file with my webpage.

Current the source allows you to change the character which a 'snowflake' is displayed as. However, I would like to be able change the property of he snowflake to be the image of a snowflake which I have created.

You are able to edit the source and this is the line which sets the character to be displayed.

```
this.snowCharacter = '&bull;';  // &bull; = bullet, &middot; is square on some systems etc.
```

Is there any way I can change this to display an image instead of a character and if so, how is this done? I have never worked with Javascript before so for any help or pointers I would be very greatful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like Snowstorm.js might have the functionality to do this already. Have you seen the information posted at http://www.bozo.us/Javascript/snowstorm/? This page suggests:

> File Structure
>
> The script looks for snow images under ./image/snow/ by
> default as shown below. If desired, this can be changed in the
> user-configurable section.

This seems to correspond to an update mentioned at the bottom of the page you linked, where it says:

> 1.2.20041121a
>
> Script moved into one file (snowstorm.js) for simplicity
>
> addEventHandler and PNG support functions updated

There's probably a ton of hacky ways to do this in JavaScript, but maybe this will lead you to a clean solution. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Find these lines

```
this.o = document.createElement('div');
this.o.innerHTML = storm.snowCharacter;
this.o.style.color = storm.snowColor;
this.o.style.position = (fixedForEverything?'fixed':'absolute');
this.o.style.width = storm.flakeWidth+'px';
this.o.style.height = storm.flakeHeight+'px';
this.o.style.fontFamily = 'arial,verdana';
this.o.style.cursor = 'default';
this.o.style.overflow = 'hidden';
this.o.style.fontWeight = 'normal';
this.o.style.zIndex = storm.zIndex;
```

The "o" here is your div element. You can add it a class by adding this line:

```
this.o.className = "myClass";
```

To remove the character remove this line:

```
this.o.innerHTML = storm.snowCharacter;
```

Than you can style the snowflake with css, the way you know it. Just give it a background image. You can also remove the lines that set the color, width and height and style them with css.

Comment: Where do I set the background image? I am a little confused with the second part of your answer.

Comment: You've marked the first answer as correct and I myself consider it better than mine. You will be better off with using the plugin's functionality.

Answer (score -1):

Use unicode `'&#10052;'` instead of `'&bull;'` in the original line like this:

this.snowCharacter = `'&#10052;'`;

this will output the snowflake '❄' character as above instead of bullet point.

you might also have to increase these values to 16 or so:

this.flakeWidth = 8;
this.flakeHeight = 8;